Get SHMMAX (max. size of system V shared memory segments) in a portable way
I need to know in a C-Programme, what is the max. size of system V shared memory segment.
On linux I can read /proc/sys/kernel/shmmax
On BSD I can use the sysctl syscall (which is availabe on older linuxes, too).
... and so on.
But is there a portable way to get that information? Or do I have to use a lot of
#ifdefs and implement a version for each OS and version???
Greetings Frank
What shall I write here? Well, I did a lot of googling, but without result...
